# NRecoPdfRenderer - Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, nreco

I am facing the issue of "Out Of Memory Exception" coming from NRecoPdfRenderer on my ASP.Net application (not using Mvc application).
[NRecor PdfRenderer web .Net Component web site](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_to_image_renderer_net.aspx)

This causes my web site to stop responding. When I remove the NReco.PdfRenderer.dll from project all works fine. Can any one tell me what is going on?

Comment: "Out of Memory" is an odd exception just for the presence of the DLL.  Just hitting any page causing this error, or is it the page that uses this library?  Did you install this via NuGet?  .Net Framework or .Net Core?

Comment: i have not installed it using NuGet instead I have added as a reference dll in my project. And I am using the trial version dll. Dont know if the purchased version will come with a licence key that will resolve the issues?

Comment: I am using .Net Framework, not .Net Core.

Comment: It just starts throwing exception on every page.

Comment: You may want to try using the NuGet version just to ensure you have the correct DLL.  Is this error happening on every page of your site, or just when you try to invoke PdfRender?

Comment: In Dev (local) and production or just production?  Again, I would try installing from NuGet to see if that helps.  I've used this NuGet package without issue before.

Comment: In test environment, it is throwing these issues. I am using this dll to extract the image in a scheduled task and then extracts the barcode from the image.

Comment: In the purchased version do you get a licence key to put in web.config? or the licence key they talk about is for support reference only? I am just thinking that whether bein the trial version has anything to do with this Out Of Memroy exception that comes after a few hours?

Comment: And i am using it in ASp.Net application, not the Mvc application. Have you used it in ASP.Net?

Comment: I haven't used it recently, but when I did, no license key was required. Last time I used it was in a console app, but I have used it in MVC web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify when 'OutOfMemoryException' occurs - when you call NReco.PdfRenderer API or when you just add a reference to the nuget package (or DLL) to your project and that's all?

In the last case I may assume that your project has another 3rd party library that scans all project assemblies (with a reflection). NReco.PdfRenderer.DLL is obfuscated and this *may* cause 'OutOfMemoryException' when its assembly is analyzed with a reflection; to fix this only way is usage of un-obfuscated build, it may be provided upon request.